# Eve returns json response like a string instead of json structure

Tags: json, http-headers, eve

I am using eve framework for back-end API purposes. I am getting the json response in a string format even with doing `return json.dumps(data)`. Eventually, I shifted to using jsonify in flask as a temporary fix.

The eve doc suggested `X_HEADERS` as the solution to specifying the http headers. But, this too didn't work.

What is the workaround to solve this issue? Should I add something to the settings file?

Btw, the API I ma using is only `GET` call.

The json data could look something like this:

```
"data": {
        "id": "'4033060000005614'",
        "x": 15000,
        "y": 15000,
        "z": 15000,
        "a": "Nothing"
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Have you checked the `Accept` request header? http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/features.html#rendering

Comment: Yes. I have also set it to application/json. Still, the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

As noted on [this issue](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/108) in the pyeve/eve project, add

```
RENDERERS = [
    'eve.render.JSONRenderer',
    # 'eve.render.XMLRenderer'
]
```

to your settings.py file (naturally you don't actually need to add the comment line).

I was having the same issue just a while ago, and this resolved the issue. Also, once you've got that added, you can add `?pretty` to your url to get the JSON pretty-printed instead of being one long jumbled string.

Comment: I'm getting a new problem, it returns default html instead json. The data looks like a json data but under html header.

Comment: @Eswar Can you give more detail? Is it that you have HTTP headers, and then JSON data as the payload (which should be expected), or you have an html tag, with strings that amount to the JSON data, but are just strings, inside the html tag (which, if you are viewing it in the browser, is to be expected)?

Comment: I have modified the question accordingly. I even tried the answer you suggested, It didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the result of a `curl` request? Or if you have httpie, an `http` request?